# jquery.smartbanner.js + prototype.js not working

Tags: jquery, prototype, smartbanner

I'm trying to use the smart-banner as described [here](http://www.adianteapps.com/blog/article/smart-app-banners-promote-your-app-in-web)

I'm using jQuery and prototype in my app with `jQuery.noConflict();` and that worked fine with other jquery-plugins, like `jcarousellite` or `bootstrap`.

I added the following refs and code into my page:

```
<meta name="google-play-app" content="app-id=com.myapppackage"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.smartbanner.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<script src="jquery.smartbanner.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $().smartbanner();
</script>
```

When I load the page, I see in my firebug the following:

> TypeError: $(...) is undefined
>
> $().smartbanner();

What am I missing?

Comment: instead of running `$().smartbanner();`, in noconflict mode you need to run `jQuery().smartbanner();`

Comment: tried that as well, isn't working either. I ended up with no-dependency solution